# Locate a lost phone that is being used

Tags: google-play-store, gps, geolocation, gps-tracking

My android cell phone was lost an year ago. But I can see someone has started using it, and that person has not yet removed my email ID. I am looking for a way to turn ON the location services of the device to get the approximate location of the phone.
Is there any way to turn ON the location services of the device remotely?

I thought of using OLA can app. But it is too heavy, I am looking for a light weight app available on play store.

Comment: This may be helpful if you can not find your phone back but want to avoid your google account id to be used on that phone: With this link https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity you can choose which devices can access or not to your google account.

Comment: Yes i am using same for loacting phone... but i somehow want to turn ON gps so as to get accurate results...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [Android Device Manager could be helpful](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager).

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Already used it a lot...  But it need GPS turned on to show the location

Comment: It should show an approximate location from the last network it connected to... if that help's

Comment: No it is not showing approximate location when the GPS of device is OFF.